# Facebook page - Update basic settings like Address, Phone, Hours, etc via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Is it possible to update facebook page's basic settings via Graph API?

If you are a page admin and when you visit https://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id=[YOUR_PAGE_ID]&sk=basic , you can edit all the basic information about the page such as

- Category
- Address
- Name
- Hours
- Description
- Price
- & more

As per api doc - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ i dont see an option for these. Are these attributes can be updated via Graph API? Is there any tool/app/extension out there doing it?

BTW, I know that you can read these info when you go to http://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID|USERNAME]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Karthik, do you have any update on your question? Currently facing the same problem, would like to programmatically change hours. Thanks in advance! Best,

Comment: Not yet dude! I doubt facebook will expose these via API in near future. Let me know if you find out any. BTW, Sorry for the delay in getting back!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making an http get request, make a post request.

An example may look like:

http://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]?method=post&access_token=[PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN]&description=[NEW_DESCRIPTION]

Answer (score 0):

Though not documented in the developer docs, you can update settings like address, hours, category etc. by making a POST request to *http://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]*

You need to have *manage_page* permission to do that.

The POST data should have the attributes in correct format. For example, address should be a JSON dictionary with fields like street, city, state etc. You can see the correct format of attributes from Graph API explorer.